# Какую технологию использовать для рендеринга React на сервере в 2023?

Tags: reactjs, ssr

Я первый раз делаю серьезное приложение и только сейчас понял, что нужно будет заняться ssr. Информация в поиске разная и современной почти нет.

Задача: генерировать html только при первой загрузке первой страницы, а дальше идёт обычное SPA
Я так понял основными вариантами будет nextJS и express.

Что выбрать, учитывая задачу? Может есть ещё какие то технологии?

.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю для решения вашей задачи отлично подойдет React + Next.js + express

Comment: Т.е. nextJS все таким может рендерить html  только на первый запрос? Я нашел только инфу, что мы генерируем html на каждую страницу + скрипт разбивается по страницам

Answer (score 0):

Перерыл тонну инфы и сделал следующией вывод:

В 2023 у нас все еще есть необходимость в ssr. Хотя гугл и яндекс уже и говорят, что ситуация со SPA улучшилась, статиска частных разработчиков показывает обратное + стоит учитывать, что у нас помимо основных поисковиков есть туча других, а еще куча социалок, где мы хотим нормального отображения превью, микросеврисов и т.д.

Варианта у нас 2:

1. Настроить SSR с помощью express. Можно например использовать готовую библиотеку iSSR информация по которой есть в достаточном объёме.
2. Если вы пишите приложение с нуля - сразу использовать NextJS в котором все уже придумано и сделано для SSR без головных болей или если у вас уже есть приложение и оно не мастодонт, переписать на NextJS. Это не очень сложно т.к. под котом у него React.

Я не эксперт и это исключительно мои выводы, если я что то не правильно написал или есть еще какие варианты - пишите, буду рад.